# Are Kotlin scope function blocks effectively inline?

Tags: kotlin, lambda, inline, primitive

I'm writing a Kotlin [inline class](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-classes.html) to make [Decimal4J](https://github.com/tools4j/decimal4j) more convenient without instantiating any objects. I'm worried that scope functions might create lambda objects, thereby making the whole thing pointless.

Consider the function **`compareTo`** in the following example.

```
/* imports and whatnot */

@JvmInline
value class Quantity(val basis: Long) {

    companion object {
        val scale: Int = 12
        val metrics: ScaleMetrics = Scales.getScaleMetrics(scale)
        val arithmetic: DecimalArithmetic = metrics.defaultArithmetic
    }

    operator fun compareTo(alt: Number): Int {
        with(arithmetic) {
            val normal = when (alt) {
                is Double     -> fromDouble(alt)
                is Float      -> fromFloat(alt)
                is Long       -> fromLong(alt)
                is BigDecimal -> fromBigDecimal(alt)
                is BigInteger -> fromBigInteger(alt)
                else          -> fromLong(alt.toLong())
            }
            return compare(basis, normal)
        }
    }
}
```

Does the `with(arithmetic)` scope create a lambda in the heap? [The docs on kotlinlang.org](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html) consistently refer to the scoped code as a lambda expression. Is there any way to use scope functions without creating objects?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of the built-in scoping functions, including [`with`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/with.html), are marked `inline`, which means the implementation gets planted directly in the code that's calling it. Once that happens, the lambda call can be optimized away.

To be more concrete, here's [the implementation](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/ea836fd46a1fef07d77c96f9d7e8d7807f793453/libraries/stdlib/src/kotlin/util/Standard.kt#L66) of `with` (with the Kotlin contracts stuff removed, since that's not relevant here)

```
public inline fun <T, R> with(receiver: T, block: T.() -> R): R {
  return receiver.block()
}
```

Extension methods are, and always have been, syntax sugar resolved at compile time, so this is effectively

```
public inline fun <T, R> with(receiver: T, block: (T) -> R): R {
  return block(receiver) // (with `this` renamed by the compiler)
}
```

So when we call

```
operator fun compareTo(alt: Number): Int {
  with (arithmetic) {
    println("Hi :)")
    println(foobar()) // Assuming foobar is a method on arithmetic
  }
}
```

The `inline` will transform this into

```
operator fun compareTo(alt: Number): Int {
  ({
    println("Hi :)")
    println(it.foobar()) // Assuming foobar is a method on arithmetic
  })(arithmetic)
}
```

And any optimizer worth its salt can see that this is a function that's immediately evaluated, so we should go ahead and do that now. What we end up with is

```
operator fun compareTo(alt: Number): Int {
  println("Hi :)")
  println(arithmetic.foobar()) // Assuming foobar is a method on arithmetic
}
```

which is what you would have written to begin with.

So, tl;dr, the compiler is smart enough to figure it out. You don't have to worry about it. It's one of the perks of working in a high-level language.

By the way, this isn't just abstract. I just compiled the above code on my own machine and then decompiled the JVM bytecode to see what it *really* did. It was quite a bit noisier (since the JVM, by necessity, has a lot of noise), but there was no lambda object allocated, and the function was just one straight shot that calls `println` twice.

In case you're interested, Kotlin takes this example function

```
fun compareTo(alt: Number): Unit {
  return with(arithmetic) {
    println("Hi :)")
    println(foobar())
  }
}
```

to this Java, after being decompiled,

```
public static final void compareTo-impl(long arg0, @NotNull Number alt) {
    Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter((Object)alt, (String)"alt");
    long l = arithmetic;
    boolean bl = false;
    boolean bl2 = false;
    long $this$compareTo_impl_u24lambda_u2d0 = l;
    boolean bl3 = false;
    String string = "Hi :)";
    boolean bl4 = false;
    System.out.println((Object)string);
    int n = so_quant.foobar-impl($this$compareTo_impl_u24lambda_u2d0);
    bl4 = false;
    System.out.println(n);
}
```

Quite a bit noisier, but the idea is exactly the same. And all of those pointless local variables will be taken care of by a good [JIT engine](https://developers.redhat.com/articles/2021/06/23/how-jit-compiler-boosts-java-performance-openjdk).

Comment: I didn't know how to answer this question other than saying "yes they are inlined". It's amazing that this much can be said! :)

Answer (score 1):

Just some additional info to help clear up the terminology that led to your confusion.

The word “lambda” is defined as a *syntax* for writing a function. The word does not describe a function itself, so the word lambda has nothing to do with whether a function object is being allocated or not.

In Kotlin, there are multiple different syntaxes you can choose from to define or refer to a function. Lambda is only one of these.

```
// lambda assigned to variable
val x: (String) -> Unit = {
    println(it)
}

// anonymous function assigned to variable
val y: (String) -> Unit = fun(input: String) {
    println(input)
}

// reference to existing named function assigned to variable
val z: (String) -> Unit = ::println

// lambda passed to higher order function
“Hello World”.let { println(it) }

// anonymous function passed to higher order function
“Hello World”.let(fun(input: Any) { println(input) })

// reference to existing named function passed to higher order function
“Hello World”.let(::println)

// existing functional reference passed to higher order function
“Hello World”.let(x)
```

There is actually no such thing as a lambda object that can be passed around. The object is a function that could have been defined using any of the above syntaxes. Once a functional reference exists, the syntax that was used to create it is irrelevant.

With inline higher order functions, as the standard library scope functions are, the compiler optimizes away the creation of the functional object altogether. Of the four higher order calls in my example above, the first three will compile to the same thing. The last is a bit different because the function `x` already exists so it will be `x` itself that is invoked in the inlined code. Its contents don’t get hoisted out and called directly in the inlined code.

The advantage of using lambda syntax for higher order inline function calls is that it enables you to use keywords for the outer scope (non-local returns), such as `return`, `continue`, or `break`.